# How to implement trie using pre-allocated memory?

Tags: c++, algorithm, full-text-search, trie, low-latency

I want to use TRIE in a low latency application to search strings between 25 to 60 chars.
String will contain english  alphabets capital and numbers.

creating trie nodes on the fly using malloc on the fly is not efficient.

It will be good to know if there are any existing implementations using memory pool etc... and once the pre-allocated memory pool overflows we need to handle by creating another memory pool in the extreme events.

Comment: Fixed-size allocations + `new` too slow = simple pool allocator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool.

Comment: How is this "obvious?" Have you profiled it?

Comment: Yes, not on trie but on other data structures which fetched memory on the fly vs pre-allocated. Results were much better with pre-allocated memory. We work on extremely low latency applications.

Comment: There is a section of [CLRS](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) in which they explore an implementation of linked list using plain old arrays (no pointers). This can be extended to any linked data structure such as trees or tries. I believe that's a very interesting although challenging option to explore. You could even make the implementation resizable (you will only need to resize the arrays when your trie grows too much, incurring the allocation overhead relatively rarely).